# How to know if Text is visible on Jetpack Compose?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-jetpack, android-jetpack-compose-text

I have a scrollable screen and I would like to do action when a specific text appears/disappears in that screen. Is there any way to do that?
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
val isVisible = remember {
  mutableStateOf(false)
}
```

In compose as of 2022, you should do something like this for state of views.

*remember()* can hold state with any value type that you want.

Answer (score 3):

Use a MutableState to hold the visibility.

`val text1Visibility = mutableStateOf(true)`

```
@Composable
fun Text(){
  if(text1Visibility.value)
    Text(text = "hello world")
}
```

the above do the trick for visible and gone, for invisible, use`Modifier.drawOpacity(0f)` for now.

```
@Composable
fun Text(){
    Text(text = "hello world", modifier = Modifier.drawOpacity(0f))
}
```